# Shopify Dawn theme question in theme.liquid file

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

What does the question mark in the following tag in the `theme.liquid` file in Shopify Dawn theme mean?.

`{%- unless settings.type_header_font.system? and settings.type_body_font.system? -%}       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.shopifycdn.com" crossorigin>     {%- endunless -%}`

I searched through the official doc about this type of syntax, but I could not find it anywhere. Please provide any reference to the official doc regarding this syntax if any.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a special liquid syntax but a property name in the [font_object](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/font) returned by [font_picker](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#font_picker) in Shopify. From the Shopify Docs about **font_object**

[system?](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/font#font-system?)

> Returns true if the font is a system font. Returns false if not.